# org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException improper-addressing

Tags: java, exception, timeout, xmpp, smack

I am getting the following Exception running a SMACK client of Windows: -

```
Sep 25, 2015 10:24:13 AM org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: improper-addressing You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
<stream:error><improper-addressing xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:994)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:935)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:950)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Google search for "org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: improper-addressing" yielded

https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.0/javadoc/index.html?org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/StreamError.html

which states

improper-addressing : a stanza sent between two servers lacks a 'to' or 'from' attribute

Beyond this I could not find any information in the Google search results about how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending to the correct port? Correct port is 5222 (not 9090 for example).